# ExtJS beginner - Samples/Extensions where is the documentation?

Tags: javascript, extjs

We have been looking at the ExtJS samples quite a few times over the years and recently decided to use it because I was looking at the samples and saw a Tree Grid and felt like "Yes this is *exactly* what I need". So I download ExtJS read a bit on the getting started/FAQ/Tutorial from the website.

Then I decide to try to use the [Tree Grid](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/treegrid/treegrid.html) to find out it's not in the documentation anywhere. so I thought it was just that the documentation was not fully updated for the latest 3.1 release so I look at the sample code to realize that most of the JS classes used for that sample are under the ux/treegrid folder, and the only place I could find that code was by downloading it directly from the sample. I never found any documentation for it anywhere.

Not only that, I also found that there are two very similar samples: [Tree Grid](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/treegrid/treegrid.html) and a [Column Tree](http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/column-tree.html) that shows how to customize the Tree Panel component, which confuses me even more. Neither have documentation for them and I can't tell if this code is supported or which one I should use or even if I should use any of them in fact; is this code production ready or just something that was thrown out there to show a nice sample and the extensibility of ExtJS ?

I noticed that many of the samples shown on ExtJS website are using components that are not part of the 'ext-all.js' and are not really documented. So I guess I am missing something about what ExtJS is supposed to be or the general philosophy behind this library ?

I guess I was expecting that most of the samples on their website would be available widgets from the library demonstrating how to use them, not showing me "Here's what you could do if you knew how to extend those components".

Any help/comments to enlighten me would be appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With user extensions, generally, you are on your own - which is not a bad thing. Your best bet is to read the code and if it's well documented, you may be able to run [jsdoc](http://jsdoc.sourceforge.net/) on it. I know this is **not** what most people want to hear, but it's best to understand the code you are adding to your project as if it was your own.

Specifically for the ux.treegrid.TreeGrid you are using, there are plenty of examples in the forums and on the net to get you rolling (I think TreeGrid is newer than the ColumnTree). If you get stuck on a specific issue, the forums and stackoverflow are the perfect places to get a quick answer.

So I guess my answer is, "Download the extension and start playing with it as if you wrote it yourself. When you run into a problem, post it here.".

Comment: This is correct.  Anything under "ux" is a User eXtension, and thus is not considered to be an "officially-supported" (read: documented) Ext component.  They are more like really advanced samples.  You should be able to get help on the Ext forums though.

Comment: I'm marking this as the right answer, cos yes I think you need to understand the code you add to a project definitely. However, understanding undocumented sub-classes of 4-5 classes of a whole fairly large framework is much work than the impression I was left with after looking at the site and the examples which lead to believe this was all built-in. That being said, it's probably the 'cleanliness' and efficiency of all the components that lead me to believe it'd be that easy.

Comment: I removed the dead extjs-ux.org link. The official docs now include the officially supported ux'es, but other than that Jonathan's advice still holds for ux'es in general.

Answer (score 2):

I have found site where you can download more or less full ExtJS documentation with ux (User eXtension)

http://www.diloc.de/blog/extdocsuite/

Short description of the link.

**ExtDocSuite**

The ExtDocSuite is an Adobe Air Application that includes the current ExtJS 3.2 Documentation in a single application to install. We provide this package, because ExtJS has not yet updated the Air Documentation app for Ext 3.2.

Features:

```
* Includes the latest Documentation for ExtJS 3.2.0
* Includes the latest ux Documentation from the examples/ folder (using ext-doc)
* Includes the latest Ext.Air Documentation. (using ext-doc)
* Search works (online)
* EXPERIMENTAL per-class search aids in finding the right documentation in big classes
* Integrated Update-System so that your documentation always stays up to date
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Ext 4.0, official ux'es have become much better supported and documented by being included with the [API docs](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api) (look under the Ext.ux.* namespace).

The Ext 3.3 ux docs are located [here](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.3.0/examples/docs/). Not sure how complete they are, so YMMV (e.g. both TreeGrid and ColumnTree are included, but without any real documentation).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the exact same problem recently when I went to use the row editor capability (attached to grid).  Being a long time ExtJS user, I never stopped to think about the lack of documentation accompanying the examples, but your comments are spot on.

For the RowEditor, [I found documentation on the internet](http://edspencer.net/2009/09/using-the-extjs-row-editor.html).  I also find the [ExtJS forums](http://yui-ext.com/forum/showthread.php?t=20793&highlight=ColumnTree) to be a great place to find suggestions, code samples, and links to documentation .